# Calculate GINI inequality coefficient from IRS SOI data

Tags: estimation, econometrics, gini

I am trying to calculate the [GINI coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gini_coefficient) from the [IRS SOI dataset](https://www.irs.gov/statistics/soi-tax-stats-individual-income-tax-statistics-2017-zip-code-data-soi) using the adjusted gross income (AGI) bins provided in the csv. I know this will not be an exact GINI index score, and only a rough estimate, but I am looking for the GINI coefficient by zipcode, and given that this dataset is laid out by zipcode, this seems like a decent way to go about this.

Can anyone point me to resources that have done something similar, in a principled or justified manner, or has anyone done something similar and could share how they did this, please?

My first thought, was to approximate this equation:
$$ G = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n} abs(x_{i}-x_{j})}{2n^2 \bar{x}} $$

I thought maybe dividing the AGI for each bin by the number of tax returns (accounting for the weight of each AGI bin), subtract the paired high to low bins, sum the absolute differences, and then divide by the total number of tax returns squared for that zipcode * 2 * weighted_mean(agi) might provide a good rough estimate. Would this be somewhat appropriate?

Comment: I do not have a reference right now, but, what you need to do is look into : 1. Gini with groupped data, or 2: parametric Gini. The second one is related to using some assumptions to fit income distribution, and using that estimate the Gini coefficient